# Most effecient way to find closest integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.2

I have a pre-defined 6 digit number, and an Entry model with a 'number' field (integer) that will have several thousand randomly generated entries per month. I need to find the best way to find the entry that is closest to the pre-defined 6 digit number.

It's basically a competition. At the start of a the month a random 6 digit number is chosen and people get to enter and are given a random number - at the end of the month the person with the closest number wins.

Anyone know what is the most efficient way to find the closest entry?

I am using Postgres 9.2 and Rails 3.2.9

Comment: Based on @Helio Santos's answer, try something like: `SELECT id ORDER BY ABS(number - 123456) ASC LIMIT 1;`, assuming the chosen number is 123456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The winner will have absolute of the difference between the predefined_number and chosen_number closest to zero.

Just have to query the picked numbers ordered by abs(predefined_number - chosen_number). The first on the list is the winner.